# Is it possible to import vmail folder from old iRedMail to new iRedMail installation?

Tags: ubuntu, email, mysql, postgresql, dovecot

Basically, what I did:

1. Copied vmail folder to my local machine.
2. Reinstalled my VPS.
3. Installed iRedMail again.
4. Created same users on the same domain.

Question is - can I somehow copy over my old vmail folder in new one to import the old emails ?

Ubuntu 12.04, iRedMail 0.8.5 on postgresql. Previous installation was on MySQL, I have full database backup.

I do not know what info to give more, surely ask for any other.

Comment: Isn't there any documentation and/or migration guide for that software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with iRedMail developers, copying over old vmail to new worked.